# How could I apply RGB values to an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm trying to apply RGB values to a HTML5 canvas that is getting all of its image data from the Bungie APIs. Basically, what I think I need to do is call these images first, then call the RGB values and use the `putImageData` function to apply the colors. What I've done so far is loop through these images and create a new canvas through JavaScript to apply the colors, but it doesn't seem to return with any changes. I'm using PHP to get the data, and JavaScript to create the canvas. Here's my code:

```
        <?php
          $decal = (array) getSingleDefinition('Decals', $group->detail->clanInfo->clanBannerData->decalId);
          $decalLink = array_values($decal);
          $primaryColor = (array) getSingleDefinition('DecalSecondaryColors', $group->detail->clanInfo->clanBannerData->decalBackgroundColorId);
          $primaryColorLink = array_values($primaryColor);
          $primaryColorRed = $primaryColorLink[0]->red;
          $primaryColorGreen = $primaryColorLink[0]->green;
          $primaryColorBlue = $primaryColorLink[0]->blue;
          $gonfalon = (array) getSingleDefinition('GonfalonDetails', $group->detail->clanInfo->clanBannerData->gonfalonDetailId);
          $gonfalonLink = array_values($gonfalon);
        ?>
        <canvas id="clanBanner" width="270" height="600">
        </canvas>
        <script>
          function loadImages(sources, callback) {
            var images = {};
            var loadedImages = 0;
            var numImages = 0;

            for(var src in sources) {
              numImages++;
            }
            for(var key in sources) {
              images[key] = new Image();
              createCanvas(sources[key]);

              images[key].onload = function() {
                if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                  callback(images);
                }
              };
              images[key].src = sources[key];
            }
          }
          var canvas = document.getElementById("clanBanner");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


          var sources = {
            foreground: "http://www.bungie.net<?php echo $decalLink[0]->foregroundImagePath ?>",
            gonfalon: "http://www.bungie.net<?php echo $gonfalonLink[0]->foregroundImagePath ?>",
          };

          loadImages(sources, function(images) {
            context.drawImage(images.foreground, 4, 35, 270, 400);
            context.drawImage(images.gonfalon, 4, 55, 270, 400);
          });

          function createCanvas(source) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = source;
            img.onload = function() {
              draw(this);
            };

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(img,0,0);
            img.style.display = "none";
            var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            var data = imageData.data;
            if(source == sources.foreground){
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4){
                data[i] = "<?php echo $primaryColorRed ?>";
                data[i + 1] = "<?php echo $primaryColorGreen ?>";
                data[i + 2] = "<?php echo $primaryColorBlue ?>";
              }
              context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            }
          }
```

If anybody has any ideas so that I could apply the variables `$primaryColorRed`, `$primaryColorGreen`, and `$primaryColorBlue` as the RGB values for the foreground image source, I would greatly appreciate it! Cheers!

Comment: :D you don't have to `<?php echo '` an entire *JavaScript* code - rather echo only the `foregroundImagePath ` right in the place you need them

Comment: You know, I tried doing it that way before, but unsuccessfully. Using <?php echo ' on the entire javascript code was the only way I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have mislead yourself with variable names. You are doing:

```
for(var src in sources) {
```

But what will the variable src actually equal in this case? It will equal "foreground" and then "gonfalon." That's not what the src of the image should be set to. I would rename src in this case to key:

```
for(var key in sources) {
    images[key] = new Image();
    createCanvas(sources[key]);
```

Besides that, you shouldn't need to create two images like you are currently. Create the image in loadImage and pass that to createCanvas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and you are right that I was stepping over myself there. I have updated my original code based on this response. However, I'm not quite sure what you mean about how I'm creating two images right now. Can you help me out a bit on this?

Comment: I am referring to the fact that you call `new Image()` twice - once in loadImage and again in createCanvas. But both of them are using the same src, so you're loading the same image twice. Upon further inspection, I think you're trying to affect the global variables canvas and context, but since you're using the var keyword you're creating new local variables with the same names in createCanvas.